# How can I get exact user details after authorisation

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I can't undertand, how I can get user information after authorisation. Now I just get user.jsp page without anything, what should i write on it. As I understand I should make servlet, but I can't undertand what I should write in it.

My filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    UserDaoImpl userDao = new UserDaoImpl();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (nonNull(session) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("login")) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("password"))) {
        User.ROLE role = (User.ROLE) session.getAttribute("role");

        moveToMenu(request, response, role);
    } else if (userDao.userIsExist(login, password)) {

        User.ROLE role = userDao.getRoleByLoginPassword(login, password);

        request.getSession().setAttribute("password", password);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("login", login);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("role", role);

        moveToMenu(request, response, role);
    } else {
        moveToMenu(request, response, User.ROLE.UNKNOWN);
    }
}

private void moveToMenu(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, User.ROLE role) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (role.equals(User.ROLE.ADMIN)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/adminPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else if (role.equals(User.ROLE.USER)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/userPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `userDao.getRoleByLoginPassword(login, password)` - this _terrifies_ me, it seems to show you storing passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I undertand that i'ts not good idea to store password as a plain text, but it's only study project and then I'll fix it.

Solution:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    UserDaoImpl dao = new UserDaoImpl();
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    int id = dao.findByLogin(login, password);

    User user = dao.findById(id);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (nonNull(session) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("user"))) {
        User role = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        moveToMenu(request, response, role.getRole());
    } else if (dao.userIsExist(login, password)) {
        User.ROLE role = dao.getRoleByLoginPassword(login, password);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
        moveToMenu(request, response, role);
    } else {
        moveToMenu(request, response, User.ROLE.UNKNOWN);
    }
}

private void moveToMenu(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, User.ROLE role) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (role.equals(User.ROLE.ADMIN)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/adminPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else if (role.equals(User.ROLE.USER)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/userPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

}

and jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>USER</title>
<jsp:include page="../view/tags/tagPage.jsp"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello USER!</h1>
<div class="container">
<h1><p class="text-center">User</p></h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${user.id}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.login}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.role}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="/delete">
                <input type="number" hidden name="id" value="${user.id}"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
name="delete" value="Delete"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p align="left"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="logout" 
role="button">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```